# How do you make org-todo apply todo state change logging to all headings, when called from a function?

Tags: org-mode, todo

## Description

When calling `org-todo` from a function, e.g., via `org-map-entries`  or `search-forward` (see example code below), then the [**todo state change logging**](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Tracking-TODO-state-changes.html#Tracking-TODO-state-changes) is only applied to **one matched heading**.

For example, calling *one* of these `mark-done` functions:

```el
(defun mark-done ()
  (interactive)
  (org-map-entries
   (lambda ()
      (org-todo "DONE"))
   "/TODO" 'file))
```

```el
(defun mark-done ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((case-fold-search nil))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (search-forward " TODO " nil t)
      (org-todo "DONE"))))
```

On this file:

```el
#+TODO: TODO(t) WAIT(w) | DONE(d!)
* WAIT W1
  SCHEDULED: <2000-01-01 Sat>

* TODO T1
  SCHEDULED: <2000-01-01 Sat>

* WAIT W2
  SCHEDULED: <2000-01-01 Sat>

* TODO T2
  SCHEDULED: <2000-01-01 Sat>
```

Results in this file (`State` line not added to `T1`, only added to `T2`):

```el
#+TODO: TODO(t) WAIT(w) | DONE(d!)
* WAIT W1
  SCHEDULED: <2000-01-01 Sat>

* DONE T1
  CLOSED: [2000-01-01 Sat 00:01] SCHEDULED: <2000-01-01 Sat>

* WAIT W2
  SCHEDULED: <2000-01-01 Sat>

* DONE T2
  CLOSED: [2000-01-01 Sat 00:01] SCHEDULED: <2000-01-01 Sat>

  - State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2000-01-01 Sat 00:01]
```

This could be a bug, but my *(e)lisp* knowledge is basically `nil`, so I am not sure how to investigate it further or if I am calling the function incorrectly.

---

## Question

How do you make `org-todo` apply **todo state change logging** to **all headings**, when called from a function? I.e., how can you replicate the behavior of manually calling `org-todo` on each headline?

---

## Version

This was run as `emacs -Q` in:

- `GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, X toolkit, Xaw scroll bars) of 2019-03-25`.
- `Org mode version 9.1.9 (release_9.1.9-65-g5e4542 @ /usr/share/emacs/26.1/lisp/org/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do it by customizing `org-log-into-drawer` which you have presumably done. The problem is that your function has a bug: it contains two calls to `org-map-entries`.
Try the following function instead:

```
(defun mark-done ()
  (interactive)
  (org-map-entries
   (lambda ()
      (org-todo "DONE"))
   "/TODO" 'file))
```

OOPS: There was an extra paren at the end of the function - sorry about that.

EDIT: I could have sworn it worked for me, but I just tried it again and I think you are right. The problem seems to be that `org-todo` adds the logging info by calling `org-add-log-setup` with some information which is stored (in global variables!) and then adds `org-add-log-note` to `post-command-hook` - but the latter is only executed at the end of a command, e.g. at the end of `org-todo` when it is called interactively, but not when it is called e.g. from `org-map-entries`. It is only executed at the end of your `mark-done`, so only the last entry gets logging information: any previous entries have been overwritten.

I think this qualifies as a bug, so it's worth reporting to the mailing list, but I'm not sure it will be easy to fix.

In the meantime, I think you can work around the problem by calling `org-add-log-note` explicitly (although that looks fraught with peril, it seems to work in my small experiments):

```
(defun mark-done ()
  (interactive)
  (org-map-entries
   (lambda ()
     (progn
      (org-todo "DONE")
      (org-add-log-note)))
   "/TODO" 'file))
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting that bug! It was not present in my original function though so the behavior persist.  What do you mean with `org-log-into-drawer`? I do modify it usually to `t`, but used the default `nil` when asking this question, but it does not fix this problem?

Comment: Seems to be working fine, thanks! What perils are you worried could ruin this?

Comment: Looking at `org-add-log-note` there's all sorts of UI elements in there. I was worried that depending on settings, you might get pop-ups that ask for additional information.